# Python - Performing t-test of estimate with standard error

Tags: python, statistics, standard-error, t-test

I'm wondering if there is a way to perform a two-tailed t-test for an estimate, given its standard error and the number of degrees of freedom? The estimate is read from another software. I have been using the t.dist.2t(abs(estimate/SE), df) in Excel, but having it directly in Python would be a huge help....

Comment: Pandas should have everything you're looking for. Also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvttbl would help with creating anova tables

Comment: Pandas? Do you have an example? The only ones I found were actually using scipy.stats on a panda dataframe. That doesn't help me at all, as I don't have the data on which the estimate was calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking for a solution, I have been provided with one by my colleague

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

est=0.0044
se=0.0826
df=767

pval = stats.t.sf(np.abs(est/se),df)*2
```